# ValueError: bad input shape in sklearn Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have 2 List `features` and `labels`. 
`features` contains **Diseases**, **Age**, **Gender** , **PIN**.
`labels` contains **Health-Plan**.

User passes the `user_input`, which is in the format of `features`. So, the code should Predict the Health-Plan for the user using `DecisionTree` of `sklearn` API.

As few parameters in `features` are `Strings`. Eg **Diseases** and **Gender**. I am encoding them using `LabelEncoder` to avoid error '`ValueError: could not convert string to float`' .

Now, after using `Label Encoder`, I got the following exception '`ValueError: bad input shape`'

How can I fix the issue and again reverse the encoding done to avoid `String to Float` error. Please help.

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
features = [['TB' , 28, 'MALE', 121001], ['TB' , 28, 'FEMALE', 121002], ['CANCER' , 28, 'MALE', 121001], ['CANCER' , 28, 'FEMALE', 121001]]
labels = ['X125434', 'X125436','X125437' , 'X125437']
user_input = ['TB' , 28, 'MALE', 121001]

le = LabelEncoder()

Y = le.fit_transform(features)
X = le.fit_transform(labels)
new_user_input = le.fit_transform(user_input)

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(new_features, new_labels)

print(clf.predict([new_ui]))
```

Comment: provide complete error message

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/subhasis.dalal/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/predict_plan.py", line 7, in <module>
    Y = le.fit_transform(features)
  File "C:\Users\subhasis.dalal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py", line 111, in fit_transform
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  
ValueError: bad input shape (4, 4)

Comment: You are using LabelEncoder wrong. It should be used on a column (single feature), not all at once. See the [examples here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features)

Answer (score 7):

It is not recommended to use the same label encoder for all the features in the data set. It is safe to create a label encoder for each column because each feature varies in terms of the values.

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import pandas as pd

features = [['TB' , 28, 'MALE', 121001], ['TB' , 28, 'FEMALE', 121002], ['CANCER' , 28, 'MALE', 121001], ['CANCER' , 28, 'FEMALE', 121001]]
labels = ['X125434', 'X125436','X125437' , 'X125437']
feature_names=['Disease','Age','Gender','PIN']

user_input = ['TB' , 28, 'MALE', 121001]


train=pd.DataFrame(data=features,columns=['Disease','Age','Gender','PIN'])
train['Labels']=labels

test=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Disease','Age','Gender','PIN'])
test.loc[len(test)]=user_input

le_disease = LabelEncoder()
le_gender = LabelEncoder()
le_labels = LabelEncoder()

train['Disease'] = le_disease.fit_transform(train['Disease'])
train['Gender'] = le_gender.fit_transform(train['Gender'])
train['Labels'] = le_labels.fit_transform(train['Labels'])


test['Disease'] = le_disease.transform(test['Disease'])
test['Gender'] = le_gender.transform(test['Gender'])


clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(train[feature_names], train['Labels'])

print(le_labels.inverse_transform(clf.predict(test[feature_names])))
```

`LabelEncoder.inverse_transform()` can be used to get the original data back.

Comment: Thanks @ram, could you please explain the following code to me:
test.loc[len(test)]=user_input

Comment: `len(test)` will give you the number of documents in the DataFrame. `test.loc[len(test)]`  will let you access the (n+1)th location, if there are already n records in the dataframe. `test.loc[len(test)]=user_input` will let you append the user_input data at the (n+1)th location.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ram

Answer (score 2):

According to [LabelEncoder documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.fit_transform), it appears you're using it in a wrong way, so the exception your are getting is saying exactly the right thing.

In your case, I think you want to encode `Diseases`, `Gender` and `Health-Plan` as integers: for instance, 
`TB` and `CANCER` will become `0` and `1`,  `MALE` and `FEMALE` will become `0` and `1` as well; `X125434`, `X125436`, `X125437` will be encoded as `0`, `1`, `2`.

Example:

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

features = [
    ['TB' , 28, 'MALE', 121001],
    ['TB' , 28, 'FEMALE', 121002],
    ['CANCER' , 28, 'MALE', 121001],
    ['CANCER' , 28, 'FEMALE', 121001]]
labels = ['X125434', 'X125436','X125437' , 'X125437']
user_input = ['TB' , 28, 'MALE', 121001]

# use different encoders for different data
le = LabelEncoder()
le_diseases = LabelEncoder()
le_gender = LabelEncoder()

diseases = [features_list[0] for features_list in features]
gender = [features_list[2] for features_list in features]

features_preprocessed = []
diseases_labels = le_diseases.fit_transform(diseases)
gender_labels = le_gender.fit_transform(gender)
for i, features_list in enumerate(features):
    features_preprocessed.append([
        diseases_labels[i],
        features[i][1],
        gender_labels[i],
        features[i][3]])

labels_preprocessed = le.fit_transform(labels)

# ... then use features_preprocessed, labels_preprocessed and the label encoders above
```

P.S. I suggest you to use pandas data frames instead of lists: as you see from the example above, it doesn't really look clean working with lists in such cases. Your features would look like:

```
import pandas as pd
features_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Diseases': ['TB' , 'TB', 'CANCER', 'CANCER'],
    'Age': [28, 28, 28, 28],
    'Gender': ['MALE', 'FEMALE', 'MALE', 'FEMALE'],
    'PIN': [121001, 121002, 121001, 121001]
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Anatoly for the prompt response, will try your approach and get back