# How to determine the correct shape when plotting linear regression?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, linear-regression

I am trying to visualize my linear regression model and unfortunately I can't quite figure out how to manage the data to plot the regression results correctly.
Below are the steps I took to perform the linear regression model, how the data looks, and the errors I'm getting.

```py
X=sale[['Dec-2018','Nov-2018', 'Oct-2018','Sep-2018','Aug-2018','Jul-2018']]
y=sale[['CLV']]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state=0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
linreg = LinearRegression()
linreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = linreg.predict(X_test)

print (X)
print (y)
X.iloc[:,:] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X.iloc[:,:])
y.iloc[:,:1] = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y.iloc[:,:1])
plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, color='black')
plt.plot(X_train, y_pred, color = 'green', linewidth=3)
plt.title('CLTV (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('CLV')
plt.show()
```

Below is the state of data and the error I'm getting:

```
   month_year  Dec-2018  Nov-2018  Oct-2018  Sep-2018  Aug-2018  Jul-2018
0               0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
1               0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
2               0.00    286.40      0.00    825.92      0.00    902.09
3               0.00      0.00      0.00    521.50      0.00      0.00
4               0.00   6354.88  16471.77   2941.72  21706.44   2796.36
5               0.00      0.00      0.00    147.70      0.00      0.00
6               0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
7               0.00    601.44    678.76      0.00    608.76   1064.08
8               0.00      0.00      0.00    519.89      0.00      0.00
9             438.50    312.73    675.38      0.00    301.70      0.00
10            998.61   9053.83   2149.30   5999.50    654.37   1070.59
11            763.06    572.59      0.00      0.00   1724.95      0.00
12            210.35      0.00    343.76    217.77      0.00      0.00
13              0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
14              0.00      0.00      0.00    918.98      0.00      0.00
15              0.00      0.00      0.00    535.50    229.50      0.00
16              0.00      0.00    392.08      0.00      0.00      0.00
17            142.60    279.50      0.00    234.00      0.00      0.00
18            111.45    100.95    217.75      0.00      0.00      0.00
19            327.40      0.00    245.80     77.31    338.20      0.00
20              0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
21              0.00    400.32      0.00   1210.32      0.00   2915.92
22              0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
23              0.00    115.23      0.00    267.80      0.00      0.00
24              0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    417.38
25              0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
26              0.00      0.00    497.83      0.00      0.00    446.09
27              0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
28              0.00    279.86      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
29            752.39   1070.14    387.80    692.24    330.44    653.00
...              ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
3898            0.00    117.54    311.63    438.14    537.95    165.00
3899            0.00      0.00      0.00   1538.41      0.00      0.00
3900          874.45      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    361.48
3901            0.00    363.20      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
3902            0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    297.06      0.00
3903            0.00     95.34      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
3904            0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
3905            0.00      0.00      0.00   4314.72      0.00      0.00
3906            0.00      0.00    448.37      0.00      0.00      0.00
3907            0.00      0.00      0.00    103.30      0.00      0.00
3908            0.00      0.00    774.76      0.00    627.27      0.00
3909            0.00   1070.40      0.00    891.90      0.00      0.00
3910            0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
3911            0.00      0.00     99.44    224.80      0.00      0.00
3912            0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00    149.48
3913            0.00    399.68      0.00      0.00      0.00    503.80
3914            0.00      0.00      0.00    312.96      0.00    488.55
3915            0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00     25.50
3916            0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
3917            0.00    171.20      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
3918          367.88      0.00    604.25      0.00    372.25    753.66
3919            0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
3920            0.00      0.00    329.61      0.00      0.00      0.00
3921            0.00      0.00    110.38      0.00      0.00      0.00
3922            0.00      0.00      0.00    173.90      0.00      0.00
3923            0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
3924            0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
3925           77.84      0.00      0.00      0.00     98.76      0.00
3926          208.00    637.71    112.99    134.90      0.00    139.89
3927            0.00      0.00   1072.00      0.00      0.00      0.00

[3928 rows x 6 columns]
month_year        CLV
0                0.00
1              401.90
2             2780.66
3             1150.80
4           121869.86
5              386.20
6             1760.96
7             5371.07
8              792.94
9             4196.01
10           29748.44
11            3822.90
12             942.34
13              92.72
14             918.98
15            1759.50
16             392.08
17            1468.12
18             430.15
19             988.71
20             253.05
21            6748.40
22             215.05
23             383.03
24             417.38
25             312.38
26            2595.24
27             134.10
28             670.65
29            5578.04
...               ...
3898          2058.09
3899          2232.49
3900          2527.10
3901           363.20
3902           793.52
3903            95.34
3904           342.92
3905          4314.72
3906           518.27
3907           103.30
3908          2274.03
3909          2338.60
3910          2128.57
3911           324.24
3912           149.48
3913           903.48
3914           801.51
3915            25.50
3916           138.90
3917           244.90
3918          2098.04
3919             0.00
3920           329.61
3921           110.38
3922           173.90
3923           180.60
3924            80.82
3925           176.60
3926          1929.93
3927          1837.28

[3928 rows x 1 columns]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-197-44d25a827a36> in <module>
      2 print (X)
      3 print (y)
----> 4 X.iloc[:,:] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X.iloc[:,:])
      5 y.iloc[:,:1] = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y.iloc[:,:1])
      6 plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, color='black')

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py in fit_transform(self, y)
    233         y : array-like of shape [n_samples]
    234         """
--> 235         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
    236         self.classes_, y = _encode(y, encode=True)
    237         return y

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in column_or_1d(y, warn)
    795         return np.ravel(y)
    796 
--> 797     raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
    798 
    799 

ValueError: bad input shape (3928, 6)
```

I've tried multiple slicing scenarios of data but it's not helping. Probably there's something to do with dimensions and it's exactly where i need help.

Comment: Thanks, just checked and y_pred has 1 column.

Comment: Have you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112414/valueerror-bad-input-shape-in-sklearn-python) primarily the last answer? I don't think you are using labelencoder correctly.

Comment: I don't see a definition of `sale`. Is that the tie-in with the database tag? Is it a numpy array?

Comment: The logic behind `y.iloc[:,:1] = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y.iloc[:,:1])` was to target another issue with data formatting. Maybe i'm doing it wrong alltogether

Comment: What issue were you trying to fix? I don't think labelencoder is necessary here. Since your index is not categorical values and you are regression on continuous data.

Comment: @pydsigner it is a pandas dataframe

Comment: @EdekiOkoh if i'm plotting without labelencoder the issue i have is: `ValueError: x and y must be the same size.` Then i don't get how can i make them the same size...

Comment: Where is that error occurring? I would bet if you [printed the shape of x_train and y_pred x_test has an extra column on y_pred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659535/valueerror-x-and-y-must-be-the-same-size). I think that that is the real issue here.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh y_pred has one column, but y_test has 2. This means i have to slice the y_test?

Comment: y_test should only be 1 column. What is the shape of y_test after this line: X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state=0)

I think thats the source of all of this.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh if i print y_test after that line:
`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state=0)
print (y_test)
y_test.info()`

that's what i'm getting (i'm dropping the data to save space)
`[982 rows x 1 columns]
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 982 entries, 582 to 3159
Data columns (total 1 columns):
CLV    982 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)`

Comment: So when does y_test get the second column?

Comment: @EdekiOkoh now after running the code once more i'm not getting the 2nd column for y_test. however, the issue about x and y not being the same size still remains. may the problem be in X values? maybe it'd be easier if i shared a notebook with you if you don't mind looking at it?

Comment: I think sharing your notebook would be the best case

Comment: @EdekiOkoh great! you are welcome to download it [here](https://dropmefiles.com/SN02r)

Answer (score 0):

`labelencoder_X.fit_transform` function is probably returning a new object (numpy array or another dataframe). 
The error is happening once you are assigning the return object to the same input using iloc.

You can try:

```
X_transf = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X)
y_transf = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y)
```

or, only the name of the variable without iloc.

Hope this can be of any help.